# How to display KeystoneJS thumbnail/preview images stored with Types.File? and schema url vs. publicPath

Tags: keystonejs

I am working with storing local images using Types.File
I have 2 questions if anyone could please help me !

1) I defined my publicPath in 'fs' and set the schema url to true,
I was expecting the url then would return something that contains the publicPath,
but instead it's got the /public/ "filename", am I defining the publicPath wrong ? or it is meant for something else?

2) I tried to use the format property of Types.File and Types.Url to return the image tag as a thumbnail/preview, but no luck with both of them, I noticed that format was removed and will get implemented back in the Types.File is it no there yet ?? or I did something wrong here as well ??

```
 var myStorage = new keystone.Storage({
     adapter: keystone.Storage.Adapters.FS,
     fs: {
         path: keystone.expandPath('./public/postimages'), // required; path where the files should be stored
         publicPath: '/postimages', // path where files will be served
     },
     schema: {
         url: true
     }
 });

 Post.add({
      *...*
      image: {
        type: Types.File,
         storage: myStorage,
         /* format: function(item, file) {
             return '<img src="/files/' + file.filename + '" style="max-width: 300px">';
         } */
       },
     image_url: {
         type: String,
        noedit: true,
     }
      *...*
 });  

 Post.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
     this.image_url = this.image ? this.image.url : '';
     next(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first issue, I had the same thing. Turns out that the FS adapter is using https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to to create the url string (code below taken from keystone's FS adapter):

```
/**
    Gets the public path of a stored file by combining the publicPath option
    with the filename in the field value
*/
FSAdapter.prototype.getFileURL = function (file) {
    var publicPath = this.options.publicPath;
    if (!publicPath) return null; // No URL.

    return url.resolve(publicPath, file.filename);
};
```

As you can see from the example on the nodejs documentation page:

```
url.resolve('/one/two/three', 'four')         // '/one/two/four'
```

So just add a "/" after you /postimages and it should work.

```
publicPath: '/postimages/'
```

Things should work after this.